# How to call func with params using call_user_func($_GET['f']);

Tags: php, function, get

i would like to know if there is a way for me to use this code, and call a function with params, i know i can call no-params functions.

Something like:

```
file.php?f=function arg1 arg2 //with a correct syntax
```

Using this code i cannot change:

```
call_user_func($_GET['f']);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I know its dangerous. its for some PoC only, nothing in production.
EDIT: As I said, i cannot change the code, i just can call  `file.php?f=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

What you're doing is **very** dangerous. You should **never** execute user-specified information (this includes, but isn't limited to, calling functions, using the passed information in `eval()` or sending it directly to a database).

#### Solution

[`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is probably easier:

```
// make "func arg1 arg2" into array('func','arg1','arg2')
$f = explode(' ', $_GET['f']);

// grab 'func' and store it
$func = $f[0];

// grab array('arg1','arg2')
$args = array_slice($f, 1);

// pas both as parameters to call_user_func_array
call_user_func_array($func, $args);
```

Comment: Hi, i know that, but i cannot change the code. Any way using call_user_func ?

Answer (score 1):

first: don't do it as this is security issue.

second:

```
$data=explode(" ",$_GET['f']);
$parameters=array_slice($data,1)
call_user_func_array($data[0],$parameters);
```

Comment: Hi, i know that, but i cannot change the code. Any way using call_user_func ?

Comment: smells like some injection flaw you found somewhere. but sadly no - you can't

Comment: Yes im helping analyse some code for injections. And I wanted to know if i was missing some injection vector for one or more parameters. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You would use an url like `?f=function&a[]=arg1&a[]=arg2` with this PHP:

```
call_user_func_array($_GET['f'], $_GET['a']);
```

---

But really, don't do this. Don't use an *unfiltered*, not validated input as function name...! A malicious user may now call any function: example `?f=shell_exec&a[]=rm+-rf+/*` which would execute the shell command `rm -rf /*` and try to delete all your files.

Comment: Hi, i know that, but i cannot change the code. Any way using call_user_func ?

Comment: @NicolasS no. no way.